# How to avoid dead lock in Task.WaitAll

Tags: c#, .net, exchangewebservices

I have multiple running tasks in Console application.  In my task I call some method from EWS Managed API. So When EWS throw exception code execution is not return to WaitAll.

```
while (index < messageData.Count)
{
    var mess = messageData[index];

    var task = new System.Threading.Tasks.Task<EventsCreationResult>(() =>
    {
        EventsCreationResult taskResult = null;
        taskResult = CreateEmail(mess, Service);
        return taskResult;
    });

    task.Start();

    tasks.Add(task);

    index = index + 1;
}

System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

And Function

```
public static EventsCreationResult CreateEmail(string folderName, EmailMessage mess)
{
    EventsCreationResult result = new EventsCreationResult();
    result.Key = mess.Subject;

    try
    {
        mess.Save(FindFolder(folderName).Id);
        result.EventsCreationLog = "Message created:" + mess.Subject;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        result.Error = ex;
    }

    return result;
}
```

So how to avoid dead lock and if its possible do not cancel task which not rise error.

Comment: Are you doing this in an asp.net/web-server/desktop UI context? Blocking on tasks is a near-perfect recipe for deadlock. Why not await the task in an async method?

Comment: I do this in Console application

Comment: Besides, as which line do you have the exception thrown?

Comment: You need to catch AggregateException

Comment: My exception in CreateEmail function mess.Save(FindFolder(folderName).Id) row or maybe ews make long request @YurySchkatula

Comment: As I understand now the problem is in long request @Crowcoder